# Estoy haciendo una aplicación de Memorama en Android Studio con Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, jetpack-compose

Tengo el código principal del juego que se divide en una función de las ocho imágenes que tengo:

```
fun cardDrawables(): List<Int> {
    return listOf(
        R.drawable.marquezm_0,
        R.drawable.marquezm_1,
        R.drawable.marquezm_2,
        R.drawable.marquezm_3,
        R.drawable.marquezm_4,
        R.drawable.marquezm_5,
        R.drawable.marquezm_6,
        R.drawable.marquezm_7,
    )
}
```

Tengo un generador de imágenes:

```
fun generateCards(cardDrawables: List<Int>): List<marquezmCard> {
    val cardShuffled = (cardDrawables + cardDrawables).shuffled()
    val cards = mutableListOf<marquezmCard>()

    for ((index, imageId) in cardShuffled.withIndex()) {
        cards.add(marquezmCard(id = index, imagenId = imageId))
    }

    return cards
}
```

Y ahora lo más importe tengo esta función que debería hacer que cada vez que clico en una imagen debe cambiar la que está puesta de fondo y mostrar una del array llamando a la función ImagenFondo y cambiando sus atributos pero no lo hace simplemente se queda la imagen de fondo por mucho que cliques, tampoco te muestra las imágenes al principio solo te muestra del fondo:

```
@Composable
fun Marquezm_game(game: Game, playersViewModel: PlayersViewModel, onGameEnd: () -> Unit) {
    var cardDrawables by remember { mutableStateOf(cardDrawables()) }
    var cards by remember { mutableStateOf(generateCards(cardDrawables)) }
    var selectedCard by remember { mutableStateOf<marquezmCard?>(null) }
    var life by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    var startDelayFinished by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var showImages by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
    var phase by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        delay(2000)
        showImages = false
        delay(3000) 
        startDelayFinished = true
    }
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(16.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Text("MEMORAMA")
        if (startDelayFinished) {
            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(16.dp)
            ) {
                
                items(cards.chunked(4)) { row ->
                    Row {
                        row.forEach { card ->
                            ImagenFondo(
                                card = card,
                                onCardClicked = {
                                    if (!it.cardUp && selectedCard == null) {

                                        card.cardUp = true
                                        selectedCard = card
                                    } else if (!it.cardUp && selectedCard != null) {

                                        card.cardUp = true
                                        
                                        
                                        if (selectedCard!!.imagenId == card.imagenId) {

                                            selectedCard!!.gameStart = true
                                            card.gameStart = true
                                            selectedCard = null
                                            playersViewModel.player1.value.score++

                                        } else {
                                            
                                            
                                            GlobalScope.launch {
                                                delay(1000)
                                                card.cardUp = false
                                                selectedCard!!.cardUp = false
                                                selectedCard = null
                                                life++
                                                if (life == 3) {
                                                    onGameEnd()
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Y por último tengo mi función ImagenFondo que debe cambiar la imagen de fondo a una de la lista según sus atributos:

```
@Composable
//Esta función jace que si la carta está levanta o coinciden pues que se den la vuelta las imagenes
//Si no pues sale la imagen por defecto marquezm_fondo
fun ImagenFondo(card: marquezmCard, onCardClicked: (marquezmCard) -> Unit) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(80.dp)
            .padding(4.dp)
            .clickable { onCardClicked(card) },
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        if (card.cardUp || card.gameStart) {
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = card.imagenId),
                contentDescription = null
            )
        } else {

            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.marquezm_fondo),
                contentDescription = "marquezm_fondo",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(80.dp)
            )
        }
    }

}
```

Los atributos de la clase Card los tengo en una carpeta Model sería esto:

```
class marquezmCard (
    val id: Int,
    var imagenId: Int,
    var cardUp: Boolean = false,
    var gameStart: Boolean = false,
)
```

No encuentro la manera de solucionar la forma en que el onClick haga correctamente su función.
Muchas gracias de antemano.